# Angular2 WebPack Deploy to Application under Default Web Site in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, webpack

I have packaged my Angular2 app with

> npm run build:prod

Which compiles to the dist folder.  I've then taken the contents of this dist folder and placed it in an Application folder under the Default Web Site of my IIS Server.

I then browse to http://[server]/[app], and nothing seems to happen, but a view of the Network tab of the browser dev tools shows the index.html is loading, and that it is making calls to the bundled js files as follows:

> http://[server]/[bundled js file]

The problem is that these calls should be:

> http://[server]/[app]/[bundled js file]

How do I fix this?

Comment: in index.html how do you have imported your client folder index.js file... try to change it to relative path from absolute path

Comment: So I looked into the index.html file, and all the assets there were referenced with href:/[asset] or src:/[asset].  I then just edited all these links to be /[app]/[asset], and the app now works.  However, I'm thinking there might be a way to configure this in the webpack build process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options for IIS. Firstly just install the app into the root of the IIS web site (no application directoy/virtual directory).

If you wish to use an application or virtual directory within IIS then you need to set a publicpath inside you webpack.dev.js

```
output: {
path: helpers.root('dist'),
publicPath: '/SWP2/',
filename: '[name].[hash].js',
chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
```

},

So in the above example I am saying that webpack should consider its generated references live in the /SWP2/ folder so the index.html will have added references like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SWP2/vendor.628ff41b723fcc2315b1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/SWP2/app.628ff41b723fcc2315b1.js"></script>
```

and when the URL looks for them it would use http://localhost/SWP2/vendor.etcetc

Keep the dev config as standard as otherwise your code wont fire except when in IIS.

Comment: don't you mean the webpack.prod.js?

Comment: Also, any idea how I can apply a similar approach to embedded css, like this @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'),
  url(assets/fonts/google/open-sans-light.woff) format('woff');
}

Comment: my problem is that in the deployed app, the url in the above css is invalid.  It also needs to be url([iis app]/assets...) instead of just url(assets/...)

Comment: allowing you have not mis-typed your comment it should be   publicPath:'/assets/'   For the css you could try putting the full url in to avoid path compilcatons (note I have not tried that so am guessing)